# js remove only one object with the same id

Tags: javascript

I have a array like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 12,
    selected: true
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    selected: true
  }
]
```

I want only remove one of the same ID, but filter remove all, how can I only remove one object?

Comment: so you want to remove duplicates? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/how-to-remove-all-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects

Comment: @cmgchess not only duplicates, maybe I have 5 of the same object I want only remove one

Comment: What happens if the second duplicate has `selected: false`? Which object do you keep out the two? The first one in the iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove one object out of all duplicates you could use this:

```
let objectIds = {};
[
  {
    id: 12,
    selected: true
  },
    ,
  {
    id: 14,
    selected: true
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    selected: true
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    selected: true
  },
  {
    id: 14,
    selected: true
  }
].filter((obj) => {
    const oid = objectIds[obj.id];
    if ( oid ) {
        oid.nr += 1;
    } else {
        return objectIds[obj.id] = {nr: 1};
    }
    if (oid.nr > 1 && !oid.removed) {
        oid.removed = true;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```